# Why does clicking on email notification links not clear out the corresponding event in the notification area?

Tags: feature-request, notifications, email

I get a lot of notifications from apps. I love the stack exchange email notification update system. it seems like I see a lot of duplicated information.

Is there any way it can be fixed so that reading/clicking through the comment in one avenue clears out all the notifications on all other platforms including web? 
It seems like I see a lot of duplicated information. Thanks ya'll!

Comment: The thing is, that right now there is no way to mark a single item as read. When you view the inbox, all items are marked as read. So to implement this request, there should probably be a mechanism that will allow single item to be marked "read" first.

Comment: I was about to write a feature request about this today (update the top bar notification icon after clicking a link in an email to read a new comment) when I found this question. Over five years later, @ShadowWizardisVaccinating do you know by any chance if SE has plans for this? I know you don't work for them but you seem to know things :)

Comment: @Marijn well, since there isn't even [tag:status-review] on this, I'm pretty sure SE has no plans to do something like this. (These days, the company "To Do List" contains bugs and feature requests marked with this tag.)